# Grouping results in sql query by a field in the result

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following format:

```
User | Entity | ID
123    AB       1
123    AB       2
543    BC       3
098    CB       4
543    BC       5
543    ZG       6
```

etc...

I want to get a result set that only returns the User/Entity pairs and their ID for the greatest ID, so this result for example:

```
User | Entity | ID
123    AB        2
098    CB        4
543    BC        5
543    ZG        6
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `group by` with `max` function

```
select user, Entity, max(id) as id
from table 
group by user, Entity
```

Comment: Ah yeah, that should have been obvious.  I was including other fields in my select rather than just joining them on afterwords, which caused the group by not to do what I needed.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CTE` and `Partition By`

Like this:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT
    Users,Entity,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Entity ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Row,
    Id
    FROM Item
)
SELECT Users, Entity, Id From CTE Where Row = 1
```

Note that we used `Order By ID DESC` as we need highest **ID**. You can delete `DESC` if you want the smallest **ID**.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dcb9/4